# parsing html using DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to parse the HTML data from a particular url provided. But i am not able to parse data as i am getting few errors.

This is my code :-

```
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML($url);  //$url is where the site url is defined
    $value = array();
    foreach($html->find($identifier) as $element) //$identifier is where div, a etc is stored
    {
        $value[] = $element->src."<br />";
    }
    print_r($value);
```

I am getting the following error

```
Call to undefined method DOMDocument::find()
```

Can anyone help me out with this .I am using cake-php 2.0

Comment: What is a specific example of `identifier`?

Comment: for example i take $identifier = div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, `DOMDocument` has no `find` method.  However, it does have a lot of very nice DOM parsing methods: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

If `$identifier` is an element name, it would make sense to use

```
foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName($identifier) as $element) {
    $value[] = $element->nodeValue + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work:

```
$html->loadHTML($url);
```

LoadHTML loads a string, this will work for example:

```
$html->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
```

Try using loadHTMLfile:

```
$html->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the documentation on the class you're using? [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is well documented on the php.net site and has no mention of a `find` method, why would you presume it does?

`DOMDocument` has a lot of methods that are familiar to any `JavaScript` developer, such as `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementById` which should be what you're looking for.

Also, if you're loading the HTML from a URL, the `DOMDocument::loadHTML` method won't work, as it expects a string containing valid HTML, not a URI.

`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile` might work with a URL parameter (can't be sure, don't have PHP installed on this computer to check), but if it doesn't you can combine `DOMDocument::loadHTML` and `file_get_contents` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the cake php documentation ... there is no find() function for domDocument Class.

How about using toArray() method of Xml class [documented here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-Xml.html#284-302)